# python requests module logging of encoding

Tags: python, logging, python-requests, python-logging

I'm using python and requests module==2.18.4

While crawling some data with requests, I used the logging module for debugging.

I want the log to look something like this:

```
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:36,940 http://localhost:8888 "GET /aaa" 200 2290
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:36,940 http://localhost:8888 "GET /aaa" 200 2290
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:36,940 http://localhost:8888 "GET /aaa" 200 2290
```

But I get this:

```
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:36,940 http://localhost:8888 "GET /aaa" 200 2290
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:36,974 EUC-JP Japanese prober hit error at byte 1765
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:36,990 EUC-KR Korean prober hit error at byte 1765
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:36,994 CP949 Korean prober hit error at byte 1765
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,009 EUC-TW Taiwan prober hit error at byte 1765
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,036 utf-8 not active
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,036 SHIFT_JIS Japanese confidence = 0.01
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,036 EUC-JP not active
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,036 GB2312 Chinese confidence = 0.01
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,036 EUC-KR not active
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,036 CP949 not active
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,036 Big5 Chinese confidence = 0.01
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,036 EUC-TW not active
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,036 windows-1251 Russian confidence = 0.01
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,038 KOI8-R Russian confidence = 0.01
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,038 ISO-8859-5 Russian confidence = 0.01
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,038 MacCyrillic Russian confidence = 0.01
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,038 IBM866 Russian confidence = 0.01
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,038 IBM855 Russian confidence = 0.01
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,038 ISO-8859-7 Greek confidence = 0.01
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,038 windows-1253 Greek confidence = 0.01
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,038 ISO-8859-5 Bulgairan confidence = 0.01
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,038 windows-1251 Bulgarian confidence = 0.01
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,038 TIS-620 Thai confidence = 0.01
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,038 ISO-8859-9 Turkish confidence = 0.47949350706
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,038 windows-1255 Hebrew confidence = 0.0
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,038 windows-1255 Hebrew confidence = 0.0
[DEBUG] 2018-01-25 03:15:37,038 windows-1255 Hebrew confidence = 0.0
...
```

I don't want that encoding in logs. How can I remove them?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue and found these the extra logs coming from [`chardet.charsetprober`](http://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) module.

To suppress these logs, put this after imports.

```
logging.getLogger('chardet.charsetprober').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

This won't print any `DEBUG` level message from [`chardet.charsetprober`](http://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) module and you will get the desired log message only.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 13):

Try setting the logging level for the module `chardet.charsetprober` to something higher than DEBUG (eg. INFO).

```
logger = logging.getLogger('chardet.charsetprober')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 3):

`response.content.decode('ISO-8859-1')`
set it for mix-charset decoding, worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I assume this issue has something to do with `r.text` (the `text` attribute of the `response` returned). Since `requests` does not know the specific encoding, it has to kinda try, thus the long list logged. To avoid this, you can either set the logging level higher (like `INFO`), or specify the encoding (`r.encoding='utf-8'` or whatever you like) before accessing `r.text`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am understanding your question properly, why can't you separate this message to different logging level.

Comment: it's automatic log of requests module... i can't separate it with my own.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, when you call the `r.text` field, the requests library tries to guess the encoding of the text.

In some cases, you could use the `r.content` field (binary response content) instead of `r.text` to avoid this guessing process.